# why is it showing undefined reference to `add'?

Tags: c

I have written a code that just basically add two numbers. file is the **self made header file**
named **xoxo.h**

```
extern int add(int r,int m);
```

This is my second file that contains the function *defination* of the function **add**.The name is
**run.c**

```
#include "xoxo.h"
int add (int i,int f) {
  return (i+f);
}
```

This is my main file **tester.c**

```
#include "xoxo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  printf("%d",add(1,2));
}
```

The error is shown as

> PS C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\New folder> gcc tester.c
> C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBwWXFk.o:tester.c:(.text+0x1e):
> undefined reference to `add' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status

plz help

Comment: `gcc tester.c run.c`

Comment: You need to compile all of the `.c` files and link them together. `gcc tester.c run.c -o tester.exe` is one way to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What source are you using to learn C? It should have already explained this to you.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile the application, you need to provide `run.c` as well, otherwise the application cannot find the implementation of `add`.

Run `gcc tester.c run.c` instead.